# Pressing enter to do same action as double click does in wpf image button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created an image button which does something if double-clicked. I want pressing enter also to do the same thing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `KeyDown` event check if `e.Key == Keys.Enter` then call the same function that the double click uses.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a WPF button then do `IsDefault="True"` and install a regular click handler.